# Batch file: save & load

Tags: batch-file, load, save, exists

I have one big problem. This app SHOULD ASK user for his name ONCE. It saves username and then when he run this app again 1st stage should be skipped and variable "name" should has his name from file with extension .user, but it does not work :/ Please Help!

```
@echo off
If NOT EXIST .settings md .settings
cd .settings
If NOT EXIST *.user goto abc
pause

If EXIST *.user set name=*.user
cd ..
pause
goto welcome
pause
:abc
cd ..
echo Hi! Welcome in my program!
set /p name=Tell me your name! 
If NOT EXIST .settings md .settings
cd .settings
echo >>%name%.user
pause

:welcome
cls
echo Welcome %name%
pause

Other commands
```

EDIT: Pauses are only for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just setting name to the string *.user. You need to parse the filename and extract just the first part.

Try:

```
If EXIST *.user (
  for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.user') do (set name=%%~fa)
)
cd ..
```

Also, to just create a blank file, you can use

```
Type nul > %name%.user
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly clear what you are trying to do.

If fred has entered his name, this line:

```
echo >>%name%.user
```

will send the ECHO status (Echo is on/off) to the file `fred.user`

If you want the file `.user` to contain "fred" then you'd need one of

```
echo %name%>.user
>.user echo %name%
```

(personally, I'd use the second)

If you then want to read the user's name from the file `.user` then

```
set /p name=<.user
```

So all together, I'd try

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
IF EXIST .user (SET /p name=<.user) ELSE (SET /p name=Your name ?)
 >.user ECHO %name%

 ECHO name is %name%
```

(I'll leave you to do the directory-manipulation)

Note that I've used `>` which means 'start a brand new file`whereas`>>`means 'append to an existing file or create a new file`

Comment: This method is also really good, but i prefer the second one. :D Thanks too! I am sure that i will use it in future! :)